# DatePicker in SwiftUI — how to change highlight colour of month and year?

Tags: swift, swiftui, datepicker

With DatePicker in SwiftUI, how can I change the highlight (and text) colour of the month and year? I tried changing the accent colour (as you see here it's red) but this doesn't change the month and year part, only some text labels and the day selection. I have `.colorScheme(.dark)` applied which changes it to light text, removing this makes the text black but doesn't have much effect on the highlight. I'd like the month and year text here to be a brighter white, with the highlight also being a paler shade. `.foregroundColor(.white)` does not have any effect here.

My code:

```swift
DatePicker(
    selection: $prManager.selectedDate,
    displayedComponents: [.date],
    label: { EmptyView() }
)
.accentColor(.red)
.datePickerStyle(.graphical)
.colorScheme(.dark)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using some of the color instance methods to get the desired effect:

```
.contrast(Double)
.colorInvert()
.colorMultiply(Color)
.brightness(Double)
.saturation(Double)
.hueRotation(Angle)
.luminanceToAlpha()
```

So in your code you might want to adjust the contrast and brightness for example.

```
...
.datePickerStyle(.graphical)
.contrast(1.5)
.brightness(0.2)
```

↳
[Documentation / SwiftUI / Drawing and graphics / Transforming colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/drawing-and-graphics#transforming-colors)

Comment: Thanks, have had a play around with these, but I can't get the exact effect I want without it affecting other parts of the datepicker in undesired ways. I didn't know about these modifiers though, so that's useful